# How to make a button non-transparent in Android?

Tags: android, button

when I just use the normal default button in android, depending on what colour the background of the intent is the colour of the button changes slightly to the colour of the background. I want it so that the button is fully opaque (like when the intent has a white background), how do I do this? thanks.

[it might only do it in android 3.1]

[image]
[image]

the same button on different backgrounds

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense. Intents don't have backgrounds. Default button looks depend on the theme applied to the view/activity. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: to have the normal button without transparency lol and yea sorry i meant the colour of the screen or activity or whatever its suspose to be called

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background for a button to any drawable. In XML, do it using the `android:background` attribute:

```
<Button
    . . .
    android:background="@drawable/my_button_bg"
    . . .
    />
```

In code, use the `setBackgroundResource` method:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_button_bg);
```

Your background drawable can be a [State List drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList), which you can use to change the background appearance when the button is pressed, has focus, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:text="@+id/Button01"
android:id="@+id/Button01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

By using android:background="@android:color/transparent" the button background will become transparent